# How to fix FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 doinbackground?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm new to Android programming and I can't pinpoint which triggers the error. Can someone please explain to me the error and how to get rid of it?

I have this errors:

```
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at com.databaseaar.Login_new$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login_new.java:82)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at com.databaseaar.Login_new$AttemptLogin.doInBackground(Login_new.java:1)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
09-16 10:09:05.529: E/AndroidRuntime(26221):    ... 4 more
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221): Activity com.databaseaar.Login_new has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c25fb0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.databaseaar.Login_new has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{42c25fb0 V.E..... R......D 0,0-684,192} that was originally added here
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:452)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:258)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:73)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:287)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at com.databaseaar.Login_new$AttemptLogin.onPreExecute(Login_new.java:66)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at com.databaseaar.Login_new$1.onClick(Login_new.java:49)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
09-16 10:09:06.459: E/WindowManager(26221):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is my code for the class Login_new and asynctask:

```
package com.databaseaar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;


     public class Login_new extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
        private EditText user, pass;
        private Button bLogin;
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 

        private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxxx.com/login_new2.php"; 
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
        private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
        public static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username";

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.login2);
            user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_email); 
            pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_password);
            bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin); 
            //bLogin.setOnClickListener(Login_new.this); 

        bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
            switch (v.getId()) { 
            case R.id.btnLogin:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
            default:
                break;
            }}
            });
        }

        class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
            // public static final String KEY_USERNAME = null;
            boolean failure = false;

             protected void onPreExecute() {
                 super.onPreExecute(); 
                 pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_new.this); 
                 pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login..."); 
                 pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
                 pDialog.setCancelable(true); 
                 pDialog.show(); 
             }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                int success;
                String username = user.getText().toString(); 
                String password = pass.getText().toString();
                try {
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); 
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                     Log.d("request!", "starting");

                     JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                     Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                    // success tag for json 
                     success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
                     if (success == 1) { 
                         Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString()); 

                     Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
                     ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                     finish();
                     startActivity(ii);

                     return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                     }else {

                       return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE); 
                   }
                   } catch (JSONException e) {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                }
                   return null; 
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
            pDialog.dismiss(); 
            if (message != null){ 
                Toast.makeText(Login_new.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
                } 
            } }}
```

PHP code:

```
       <?php
 $con=mysqli_connect("xxxx","xxxx","xxxx","xxxx");

  $password=$_POST["password"];
  $username=$_POST["username"];

if (!empty($_POST)) { 
if (empty($_POST['username']) || empty($_POST['password'])) {
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "One or both of the fields are empty .";
}
$query = " SELECT * FROM login WHERE username = '$username'and password='$password'";

$sql1=mysql_query($query);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1);

if (!empty($row)) {
$response["success"] = 1;
 $response["message"] = "You have been sucessfully login";
 die(json_encode($response));
 }else{
 $response["success"] = 0;
 $response["message"] = "invalid username or password ";
 die(json_encode($response));
 }}
  else{
  $response["success"] = 0;
  $response["message"] = " One or both of the fields are empty ";
    die(json_encode($response));
    }
mysql_close();
?>
```

My JSON httpRequest

```
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
    // Making HTTP Request
    try {
        // check for request method
        if (method == "POST") {
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHTTPClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } else if (method == "GET") {


            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer error", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    return jsonObj;
}
```

New error log cat:

```
    09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <b>Deprecated</b>:  mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in <b>/home/u747670603/public_html/login_new2.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'u747670603'@'10.2.1.25' (using password: NO) in <b>/home/u747670603/public_html/login_new2.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in <b>/home/u747670603/public_html/login_new2.php</b> on line <b>14</b><br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): <b>Warning</b>:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in <b>/home/u747670603/public_html/login_new2.php</b> on line <b>15</b><br />
09-08 08:30:14.854: E/Response(2297): {"success":0,"message":"invalid username or password "}
```

Comment: check LOGIN_URL is correct or not...

Comment: should refresh or start activity in UI thread.

Comment: login url is correct

Comment: check my edited ans.

Comment: @Sasya Have you tried my solution?and what is `Login_new.java:82`?

Comment: java:82 is -->  Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the Crash dump suggests, It's the problem with the progressDialog which initiates in the onPreExecute() method. But in your doInBackground() method starts an activity on some condition without dismissing the progressDialog. This leads to Window Leakage shown in the crash dump.

doInBackground() should be used to do the networking or other harder tasks. UI related API's should not be called inside this method as this method runs on different thread(Not on Main GUI thread). So I suggest you to move the code that starts the new activity to onPostExecute() method and the progressDialog should be dismissed before launching the new activity.

Here is a sample code.

```
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    // public static final String KEY_USERNAME = null;
    boolean failure = false;
    String username, password;

     protected void onPreExecute() {
         super.onPreExecute(); 
         pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_new.this); 
         pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login..."); 
         pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
         pDialog.setCancelable(true); 
         pDialog.show();

        username = user.getText().toString(); 
        password = pass.getText().toString(); 
     }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        int success;

        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); 
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

             Log.d("request!", "starting");

             return jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params).toString();
         } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
         }
}

protected void onPostExecute(String message) {
    pDialog.dismiss(); 

    if (message != null) {
        Toast.makeText(Login_new.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        try {
             JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);

             // success tag for json 
             int success = object.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
             if (success == 1) { 
                 Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString()); 
                 Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
                 ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                 startActivity(ii);
                 finish();
             }
         } catch (JSONException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
 }
```

**Edit**

```
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();

    /*
     * This line will print the server response. 
     * Check this response and make changes to the PHP&MySQL accordingly.
     * Post this response for further help
     */
    Log.e ("Response", json);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer error", "Error converting result" + e.toString());
}
```

**EDIT**
Here is a sample PHP login script (Add the $username, $password assignment statement before using them)
    login.php

```
require_once('Database.php');

$db = new Database();

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username = :username AND password = :password");
$stmt->bindParam(':username', $username);
$stmt->bindParam(':password', $password);
$stmt->execute();

if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {
       $result['status'] = 1;
       $result['msg'] = "Successfully logged in";
} else {
       $result['status'] = 0;
       $result['msg'] = "Invalid login credentials";
}

echo json_encode($result);
```

Create a new PHP class file Database.php add the below code in it.

```
<?php

class Database extends PDO {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbName', 'username', 'password');     
        parent::setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }
}
```

Don't forget to change the host name, DB name, username and password in the above class constructor.

Comment: can you show me how to code in doInBackground() ? if i modify the onPostExecute like yours

Comment: can you show me how the code look like in doInBackground() ?

Comment: thanks samuel, but still have an erro like this,                                   09-08 11:37:52.874: E/JSON Parser(2948): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: This error happens because you have an incorrect JSON from the Server. I think your server returns some error message. Check your PHP code at the server

Comment: Check the response message what you're after you make the server request.

Comment: Post the implementation of jsonParser.makeHttpRequest() method

Comment: i've updated my code of HttpRequest() method. look at the code

Comment: I've updated my answer. Post the response from server.

Comment: i get a new error again... :( , error log cat i've updated

Comment: Well, Now you know your errors. Solve them. Use PDO methods instead of mysql_query() which is deprecated now.

Comment: thank you for your effort for helping me... but i still confused for this error about mysql_query()

Comment: mysql_query() is old method of database interaction from PHP. It's open to lot of vulnerabilities. I've updated my code. Just follow that.

Comment: Read more about PDO and use that throughout your project.

Comment: i was updated my php code as your... but, give me error on this "if ($stmt->rowCount() == 1) {"  --> E/Response(2540): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in <b>

Comment: put a ; before the if statement

Comment: ok... i put ; sign before if statement, but there is a new error again :( on E/Response(2540): <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ';' in <b> --> is below $db = new Database();

Comment: Great. Keep it up

Answer (score 0):

why **finish()** before start activity?

```
Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
                     ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                     finish();
                     startActivity(ii);
```

your Code should be

```
 Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
                         ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);

                       startActivity(ii);
```

and in post execute do **finish();**

do your code like this.

```
 public class Login_new extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button bLogin;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser(); 

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://xxxx.com/login_new2.php"; 
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success"; 
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME ="username";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
        setContentView(R.layout.login2);
        user = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_email); 
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ET_password);
        bLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin); 
        //bLogin.setOnClickListener(Login_new.this); 

    bLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
        switch (v.getId()) { 
        case R.id.btnLogin:
            new AttemptLogin().execute();
        default:
            break;
        }}
        });
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean> {
        // public static final String KEY_USERNAME = null;
        boolean failure = false;

         protected void onPreExecute() {
             super.onPreExecute(); 
             pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login_new.this); 
             pDialog.setMessage("Attempting for login..."); 
             pDialog.setIndeterminate(false); 
             pDialog.setCancelable(true); 
             pDialog.show(); 
         }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;
            String username = user.getText().toString(); 
            String password = pass.getText().toString();
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username)); 
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                 Log.d("request!", "starting");

                 JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST", params);
                 Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // success tag for json 
                 success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS); 
                 if (success == 1) { 
                     Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString()); 

                 Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
                 ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
               startActivity(ii);
                 failure = false;
                 return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                 }else {

                   return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE); 
               }
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
               return failur; 
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(boolean fail) {
        pDialog.dismiss(); 
        if (message == true){ 
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(Login_new.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
            } 
        } }}
```

Comment: i was deleted , but nothing happened, still in error

Answer (score 0):

The reason is json.toString() sometimes is null based on your server code, so you're getting NullPointerException.

remove that line

```
 Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());
 Log.d("Successfully Login!", json.toString());
```

Comment: i have remove both of them, but still give me an error

Comment: then you check url in browser its wrok proper or not?

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/u747670603/public_html/login_new2.php on line 2

Answer (score 0):

Put the below code in `onPostExecute()` rather than `doInBackground()`

```
Intent ii = new Intent(Login_new.this,MainActivity.class);
             ii.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
             finish();
             startActivity(ii);
```

The reason is you are trying to finish the current `activity` and try to start a new `activity` while the `progressdialog` is still showing that's why there is leaked window error showing there.And also the `doInBackground()` method is expecting `String` in return.